# Take a string out of a tuple - python

Tags: python

I have a tuple and a random string:

```
AllSands = "GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"
found_sand = random.choice(AllSands)
```

But afterwards, I would like to take the random string out of the tuple, so the random part can be run again, without it being the same color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mutate a `tuple`, only create new `tuple`s. It would be easier to do if you used a `list`:

```
AllSands = ["GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"]
found_sand = random.choice(AllSands)
AllSands.remove(found_sand)
```

Of course, even easier is to just shuffle and `pop` as needed, which removes the `O(n)` search and copy down work of `remove`:

```
AllSands = ["GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"]
random.shuffle(AllSands)
found_sand = AllSands.pop()  # Each time you call pop, you "find" a new value
```

Comment: I like your answer.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable, so they can't be removed.  You can create a new one with fewer elements.

```
>>> AllSands = "GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"
>>> AllSands = AllSands[1:]
>>> AllSands
('RED', 'PINK', 'BLACK', 'WHITE', 'ORANGE', 'PURPLE', 'BROWN', 'GREY')
```

But instead you may want to just iterate over the shuffled tuple:

```
AllSands = "GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"
>>> all_ = list(AllSands)
>>> random.shuffle(all_)
>>> all_
['WHITE', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'RED', 'PINK', 'ORANGE', 'GREY', 'GREEN', 'BROWN']
>>> random.shuffle(all_)
>>> all_
['GREEN', 'BLACK', 'PURPLE', 'GREY', 'PINK', 'BROWN', 'RED', 'WHITE', 'ORANGE']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just make `AllSands` a list and `shuffle` it

```
>>> AllSands = ["GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"]
>>> import random
>>> random.shuffle(AllSands)
>>> AllSands
['BROWN', 'WHITE', 'ORANGE', 'GREY', 'PINK', 'PURPLE', 'GREEN', 'BLACK', 'RED']
```

If you know you won't need the whole list, you can use `sample` intead

```
>>> random.sample(AllSands, 3)
['PINK', 'BROWN', 'ORANGE']
```

These ways are more efficient than choosing one random item at a time and then removing it from the list/tuple

You could also have a function that returns an iterator, like this

```
>>> def shuffler(items):
...     items = list(items)
...     random.shuffle(items)
...     return iter(items)
... 
>>> sands = shuffler(AllSands)
>>> next(sands)
'RED'
>>> next(sands)
'PURPLE'
>>> next(sands)
'WHITE'
>>> next(sands)
'GREEN'
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way would be to replace your tuple with a list and do the following:

```
AllSands = ["GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"]
index = random.randrange(len(AllSands))
found_sand = AllSands.pop(index)
```

Comment: It's not really that efficient as `pop(index)` needs to move a bunch of items down the list each time it is called. see @ShadowRanger's answer which avoids this by only popping from the end of the list

Comment: Doesn't shuffle move bunch of items in the list too?

Comment: Yes, but only once. This is the difference between being O(n) and O(n**2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.shuffle()` to get what you want, but if you really want to "delete" an element from a tuple (actually tuple is inmutable), Try this:

```
import random 
AllSands = "GREEN", "RED", "PINK", "BLACK", "WHITE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE", "BROWN", "GREY"
found_sand = random.choice(AllSands)
AllSands = tuple( x for x in AllSands if x != found_sand)
found_sand = random.choice(AllSands)
```